# Do stacks with non-algebraic automorphism groups arise in nature?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks

Do stacks parametrizing objects with non-algebraic automorphism groups happen in nature e.g. in complex analysis or number theory?

For example can the automorphism groups be non-projective complex tori?

Comment: A very important example is the moduli stack of formal groups, whose importance for homotopy theory can hardly be overstated.